# Cannot Import Pygame to Python 3.7 IDLE (64-bit) Despite Installing Pygame Using Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

Is there a way to fix this error of importing pygame to python 3.7 IDLE (64-bit):

```
Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
>>>
```

I have already installed pygame using pip installation:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Roy>pip3 list
Package                    Version
---------------------- -----------
astunparse             1.6.3
pip                    20.1.1
pygame                 1.9.6
setuptools             41.2.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit 1.6.0.post3
tensorflow             2.2.0
wheel                  0.34.2
```

`   C:\Users\Roy>pip install pip
    Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\roy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
    32\lib\site-packages (20.1.1)

```
C:\Users\Roy> C:\Users\Roy>pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\roy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\lib\site-packages (0.34.2)

C:\Users\Roy> C:\Users\Roy>pip3 --version
pip 20.1.1 from c:\users\roy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 
3.7)
```

So I don't know what the issue is here. If I pip installed pygame, should it show up in the IDLE environment where I can import it?

By the way, I have Anaconda installed to my computer for using Data Science libraries and Jupyter notebook which all work fine. It's just pygame that doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Also, I got another error on python path but it works for pip3 path.

```
C:\Users\Roy>python --version
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I noticed that the pip path location is different from the Python 3.7 location which may have been the reason but I am not sure. Here is where my pip and pygame and wheel are located in:

```
C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
```

And where my Python 3.7 location is:

```
C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7
```

Comment: Check to see that the python interpreter that you're running from the command line is the same one that is run when you run pip3. You can get this info by running `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` in your interpreter instance.

Comment: Check if you installed pygame in a virtual environment.

Comment: On a mac, you have to write python3, or python3.7

Comment: I imported pygame in Pycharm successfully and installed it in a different folder than the Python 3.7 folder. How do I install pygame in a virtual environment in IDLE?

Comment: @Stephen I ran those two commands and I got:    
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe

Comment: @DewMan Notice the different paths for pip3 and your python interpreter. Your pip3 is running in the environment of a 32bit install of python 3.7, where as your interpreter instance is running for a different, 64bit, installation. You're going to want to fix your path, or setup a virtual environment and use that (this is usually cleaner anyway).

Comment: How do I set up a virtual environment with cmd for IDLE?

Comment: @Stephen I just created a new virtual environment and installed pygame using: pip3 install wheel and pip3 install pygame. Then I launched Python IDLE into the virtual environment using command: python -m idlelib.idle and it surprisingly worked. Also I got the command: python -m pygame.examples.aliens to work too in the virtual environment. My only question left is how do I make the virtual environment the default environment now since pygame only works there (not outside the environment) and also use Python IDLE in the same environment by default?

Comment: @Stephen I successfully imported pygame (I think) in the new virtual environment. However, I wanted to check the version I have of pygame using command: print(pygame.version.ver) and I get the error: AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'version'

Comment: @Stephen Now I get another error called AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' when I typed command: pygame.init()

Comment: @Stephen I noticed that my pygame import worked for Python IDLE (32-bit) but not for Python (64-bit).

Comment: @Stephen I don't think I installed pygame correctly because I keep getting error after error even after creating a virtual environment.

Comment: @Stephen Ok update: pygame only works for 32-bit Python IDLE, but it doesn't work for Python IDLE for 64-bit. How do I make it work for both?

Comment: You'll need the appropriate distribution of PyGame for the 64 bit installation installed and available so that you can import it.

Comment: @Stephen So the pygame I installed using pip3 install pygame in cmd in virtual environment is 32-bit by default? How do I do the same for 64-bit version using pip3? I got the pygame to work for 32-bit version fine now.